# On independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a probability space $(\Omega, M, P)$
and non-negative integrable functions on $\Omega \times [0,1]$, $F_1(\omega, t)$
and $F_2(\omega, t)$. For each $t \in [0,1]$ we have that
$F_1(\omega, t)$ and $F_2(\omega, t)$ are independent. 
Does it then follow for any interval $(a, b)$ contained in $[0,1]$
that we have
$$
\int_a^b F_1(\omega, t) \ dt
$$
and $F_2(\omega, t)$ are independent?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The discrete version might be easier to explain: assume that $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are independent and that $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are independent, does it follow that $X_1+X_2$ and $Y_1+Y_2$ are independent?

Counterexample: try $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent, and $Y_1=X_2$, $Y_2=X_1$, then $X_1+X_2=Y_1+Y_2$ hence $X_1+X_2$ and $Y_1+Y_2$ are independent if and only if $X_1+X_2=Y_1+Y_2$ is degenerate.